# Unable to add incoming Webhook to MS Team as a connector

Tags: microsoft-teams, connector

Error
:-(
Something went wrong.
The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.:Unified groups aren't supported.
RequestId: b47dce03-3b1b-e0ca-589c-4340a4fd3ea9
Server: BN6PR1001MB2353
Date: 12/19/2022 8:40:05 AM

Unable to add incoming webhook to MS team for Servicenow integration

Comment: We tried to configure a MS Teams Incoming Webhook connector and it got added successfully. Microsoft Teams Version 1.5.00.34469 https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FeOp.png

Comment: Hello This may work for you but not working for us. getting the same above result. I reached put MSFT and they said Dev team can help on this.

Comment: We have raised an ICM for this issue and concerned team is looking into it. We will inform you once we have further update. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please try to delete all cookies and try again. It happens possibly because of expired cookies stored in the browser.

Comment: And also, If the mailbox has MailUser/SharedMailbox as recipient type then Connectors won't work for such mailboxes. It should be a regular mailbox.

Comment: Thanks!!! was able to add connector after re-installing the MS teams.